# Can't seem to get values from Nsdictionnary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm a beginner in ios programming and I found myself having some trouble with Nsdictionnary.

I have a NSdictionnary which looks like this (when I log it like this : NSLog( @"%@", self.infologin );):

```
    {
    Admin =     {
        login = admin;
        pass = mdp;
    };
}
```

And I would like to get the value for "login", so I tried many things like :

```
self.infologin[@"login"];
```

but I can't find a way to make it work.

If needed, here is the way I get my NSdictionnary :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    self.infologin = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
```

And here is my Json content :

```
{"Admin":{"login":"admin","pass":"mdp"}}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `self.infologin[@"Admin"][@"login"]`, because `login` is inside the `Admin` dictionary.

So first you need to get the `Admin` dictionary, and then get `login` from that.

Comment: Just to note that the same can be achieved via `[self.infologin valueForKeyPath:@"Admin.login"];`